# How do I add new clients to mutual certificate based AWS client VPN?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, vpn, pki

When setting up a mutual certificate based AWS client vpn the instructions show how to make the client and server certs together, shown [here](https://gist.github.com/monkut/16d79d98752039c0e36dcb0dbcb0a9b8), for example.

I understand how to make multiple client certs, one for each user, at the time the server cert is created, but how do I create a new cert later on, without replacing the existing cert and forcing those users to install new client certs?